# how to use colorful icons in navigation drawer menu?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-icons

My navigation app drawers has svg format icons like this:
[image]

[image]

but when i add these icons in vector assets and use it in my app colors of these icons turns grey.Is there anyway i can use these icons as it is(colorful)
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); //disable tint on each icon
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Thanks for improving the answer's reference value and making it more understandable!